# How to prevent browsers from retrying failed POST requests (and check for internet connectivity)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, connectivity

I have a site intended for mobile users that would check the connectivity for every POST requests. If there is no internet connectivity, I will prompt out an error message for the user. Also, I would like to have a transition effect indicating that the form is being submitted.

**I have the following code:**

```
var progress = 0;

$('div').on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    var thisform = this;

    if (progress === 1) {

        // check internet connection     
        var connection = hostReachable();

        if (!connection) {
            alert('No connection');
            setTimeout(function () { // re-allow submission after 8000 ms (not immediately to avoid browser retry)
                progress = 0;
            }, 8000);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (progress === 0) { // first submit

        // updated progress value            
        progress = 1;

        //form transition               
        $('.spinner').show('fast', function () {
            $('.pagecontent').fadeOut('fast');
            thisform.submit();
        });
    } else {
        // prevent submit retries when no connectivity
        return false;
    }
});
```

where `hostReachable()` is a function for checking connectivity using xhr request.

The problem is now after the `thisform.submit();` the form submission event seems to not triggered again. So the code inside `if (progress === 1)` is never run.

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: during your transition you are submitting the form. i am not sure what you are expecting from your code.

Answer (score 0):

`thisform.submit()` will not trigger the form submit event handler because if you think about it'll be an infinite loop. What you have to do is programmatically click the button to trigger form submit event.

```
$('#submit-button').trigger('click');
```

**Demo:**

```js
var progress = 0;

$('div').on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    var thisform = this;

    if (progress === 1) {

        // check internet connection     
        var connection = hostReachable();

        if (!connection) {
            alert('No connection');
            setTimeout(function () { // re-allow submission after 8000 ms (not immediately to avoid browser retry)
                progress = 0;
            }, 8000);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (progress === 0) { // first submit

        // updated progress value            
        progress = 1;

        //form transition               
        $('.spinner').show('fast', function () {
            $('.pagecontent').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#submit-button').trigger('click');
        });

    } else {
        // prevent submit retries when no connectivity
        return false;
    }
});

function hostReachable() {}
```

```css
.spinner {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form>
        <div class="spinner">loading</div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit-button"/>
    </form>
</div>
```